# trying to use the Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I am trying to change the navigation style of my Navbar as I scroll from the top section to the next and other sections,  but I am having trouble with the js code and I don't know why it is not working the way I want it to. I am using Intersection Observer but somehow, it doesn't apply in my website.

```js
   /* About Us JavaScript */
    
    const header = document.querySelector("header");
    const top_section = document.querySelector(".top_section");
    
    const top_sectionOptions = {
        rootMargin: "-200px 0px 0px 0px"
    };
    
    const top_sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
        entries, top_sectionObserver){
            entries.forEach(entry =>{
                if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
                    header.classList.add("nav-scrolled");
                } else { 
                    header.classList.remove("nav-scrolled");
                }
            })
        }, top_sectionOptions);
    
        top_sectionObserver.observe(top_section);
```

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    }
    
    *::before,
    *::after {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .top_section {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) url(../images/balcony.jpg);
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-blend-mode: darken;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .nav_brand {
      color: skyblue;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    
    header {
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .nav_middle_section {
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    
    .middle_section_link {
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      margin-right: 55px;
      font-weight: 300;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .middle_section_link::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -5px;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0%;
      height: 2px;
      background: skyblue;
      transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    
    .middle_section_link:hover,
    .middle_section_link:active {
      color: skyblue;
    }
    
    .middle_section_link:hover::after {
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .caption span.border {
      background-color: #111;
      color: skyblue;
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }
    
    .nav-scrolled {
      background-color: red;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css" />
        <script src="javascript/ctrl.js"></script>
        <title>About Us</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="top_section">
          <!-- Navigation Bar and Brand -->
    
          <header>
            <h2 class="nav_brand">BK-Lodge</h2>
            <div class="nav_middle_section">
              <a href="#" class="middle_section_link">Home</a>
              <a href="#" class="middle_section_link">About</a>
              <a href="#" class="middle_section_link">Account</a>
              <a href="#" class="middle_section_link">Room Services</a>
              <a href="#" class="middle_section_link">Developers</a>
            </div>
          </header>
          <!-- Section Tag -->
    
          <div class="caption">
            <span class="border">About Us</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- First Body -->
    
        <div class="body_section">
          <h2>About this Area</h2>
          <h3>Madina</h3>
          <p>
            Bonsukoda Lodge is located in Madina. The area's natural beauty can be
            seen at Labadi Beach and Achimota Forest, while Wheel Story House and
            National Theatre of Ghana are cultural highlights. Legon Botanical
            Gardens and Accra Zoo and Endangered Primate Breeding Centre are also
            worth visiting.
          </p>
          <img src="images/front-elevation.jpg" alt="hall" />
        </div>
        <hr />
    
        <!-- Second Body -->
    
        <div class="middle_section">
          <h2>About this property</h2>
          <h3>Bonsukoda Lodge</h3>
          <p>
            3-star guesthouse near Madina Market Along with a bar/lounge, this
            guesthouse has laundry facilities and a 24-hour front desk. Free WiFi in
            public areas and free self parking are also provided. All 24 rooms offer
            free WiFi, refrigerators, and room service. Other amenities available to
            guests include rainfall showerheads, showers, and desks. Bonsukoda Lodge
            offers 24 air-conditioned accommodations with complimentary toiletries.
            Guests can surf the web using the complimentary wireless Internet
            access. Bathrooms include showers with rainfall showerheads.
            Housekeeping is offered daily and irons/ironing boards can be requested.
          </p>
          <img src="images/lodge-front.jpg" alt="lodge front" />
        </div>
        <hr />
    
        <!-- Grid Section -->
    
        <div class="grid_section">
          <h2>Cleaning and safety</h2>
          <h3>Enhanced cleanliness measures</h3>
          <p>
            Disinfectant is used to clean the property High-touch surfaces are
            cleaned and disinfected Sheets and towels are washed at 60°C/140°F or
            hotter Follows industry cleaning and disinfection practices of COVID-19
            Guidelines (WHO)
          </p>
          <h3>Social distancing</h3>
          <p>Guest rooms kept vacant for 48 hours between stays</p>
          <h3>Safety measures</h3>
          <p>
            Personal protective equipment worn by staff Temperature checks given to
            staff Temperature checks available for guests Masks and gloves available
            Masks are required at the property Hand sanitizer provided
          </p>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Footer -->
    
        <footer class="white-section" id="footer">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <i class="social-icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="social-icon fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="social-icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
            <i class="social-icon fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <p>© Copyright 2022 Bonsukoda Lodge</p>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks like rootmargin is wrong. Why is it minus 200?